# min/max on differences of DataFrame columns in Julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

When I try to retrieve the maximums of differences of columns in a DataFrame I get an error. What is wrong?

```
using DataFrames

a = [2,4,10,4,8,8]
b = [5,9,7,2,8,7]
c = [2,9,7,6,8,1]

df = DataFrame(A = a, B = b, C = c)
df[2,:A] = NA
df[3,:C] = NA

ab=df[:A] - df[:B]
bc=df[:B] - df[:C]
ac=df[:A] - df[:C]

df[:max] = max(ab, bc, ac)

println(df)
```

=> LoadError: MethodError: no method matching isless(::DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}, ::Array{Any,1})

Doing the maximum of either `df[:max] = max(ab, bc)` or `df[:max] = max(a, b, c)` works as expected.

Can anybody clarify what's going on? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the return types:

```
julia> typeof(ab)
DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}

julia> typeof(bc)
DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}

julia> typeof(ac)
DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}

julia> typeof(max(ab, bc))
Array{Any,1}
```

That last one is the issue. Julia is complaining that it cannot compare a `DataArray{Int64,1}` with an `Array{Any,1}`. This does not happen with the original `Int` arrays because they have no `NA`. As noted in the [`DataFrames` docs](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#the-na-value), `NA` poisons array operations.

Observe that the following code works fine because it has no `NA`, so the return type of `max` is fully specified:

```
df2 = DataFrame(A = a, B = b, C = c)
df2[:max] = max(a, b, c)
typeof(df2[:max]) ### DataArrays.DataArray{Int64,1}
```

Your best option is to impute or purge the `NA` from your `DataFrame` before computing maxima. An easy way to purge `NA` by row is

```
df3 = DataFrames.na_omit(df)[1]
```

Comment: not to my knowledge. `na_omit` is not exported by `DataFrames`. it is still there in v0.8.5, though that may change in the future